# iOS Swift background state on restart

Tags: ios, swift, background, appdelegate

If my app is in background/suspend mode, it will fetch data and work fine. But when I restart the iPhone the app isn't more in the background mode.
Is it possible on device start, that the app will be in the same mode (background mode) as before the restart without user activity?

Answer (score 2):

Afaik, this is only possible if you specify `voip` as your background mode.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW22